Parsing data from python into javascript to then put into Chart JS
Originally I had a basic line chart. I then tried to parse data into the js portion of the html using jinja but obviously that didn't work. I then tried to parse directly into js. Unsuccessful. Now I tried using a json file and grabbing the values. Again Unsuccessful.
Currently trying to iterate over it and it's not working
I tried parsing through js, unsuccessful, tried jinja, tried using a json file
fetch('Solo-Trade-Journal/monthly_data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Parse the JSON data and extract the dates and growth values
        var labels = data.map(item => item.date);
        var growth = data.map(item => item.growth);

        // Select the canvas element and create a new Chart object
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart').getContext('2d');
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line', // specify the chart type
            data: {
                labels: labels, // these labels appear on the x-axis
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First Dataset', // the name of this dataset (optional)
                    data: growth, // the data points for this dataset
                    fill: false, // don't fill the area under the line
                    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', // the color of the line
                    tension: 0.1 // the smoothness of the line
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true, // make the chart responsive
            }
        });
    });

# Iterating over data and extracting required information
        monthly_list = []
        for entry in data['data']:
            data_info = {
                'date': entry['date'],
                'growth': entry['growth'],
            }
            monthly_list.append(data_info)

        # Printing the list of data dictionaries
        print("Data list:", monthly_list)
        monthly_list_json = json.dumps(monthly_list)
        # Writing the data to a JSON file
        with open('monthly_data.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(monthly_list_json)


Are you getting any errors in the console?

Your code to create the JSON file looks fine.

There's not enough information - there are a lot of possibilities for the application to fail. Is the fetch call successful? - it won't be unless you get your page through a web server. Please edit your post to add the information about possible errors in console, as requested, and also the results of your debugging the javascript code - for instance what do you get on console.log(data)

Use json dump to create a json file that will be interpreted in the javascript
json_data = json.dumps(monthly_growth)


you then want to parse this json file in your javascript like this, usingjson parse and making it safe. you can also add another feature to the pass using |tojson if your variable thing you're trying to pass isn't passed as a json and just passed as a dictionary:
const monthlyGrowth = JSON.parse('{{ json_data | safe }}')

you can then do the necessary abstractions for the data. Here's mine:
        const chartContainer = document.getElementById('container')
        const monthlyGrowth = JSON.parse('{{ json_data | safe }}')
        const dataPoints = Object.entries(monthlyGrowth).map(([time, value]) => ({ time, value }));

        const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(chartContainer, {width: chartContainer.clientWidth, height: chartContainer.clientHeight});
        const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
        lineSeries.setData(dataPoints);

